# Minimizing and optimizing NGINX vhost config

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to optimize/minimize the config posted below?

I feel that it should be possible to merge all the redirects into something more simple.

http:// & http://www & https://www > https://

Though I've had issues and settled.

I understand variables are not supported in NGINX config, so I have to manually define the log locations for example. Would there be a way to set a default location for all vhosts?

I use the same `ssl-params.conf` file for all vhosts. Can this be defaulted and disabled on a per-vhost basis?

```
# Redirect http:// & http://www to https://
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect https://www to https://
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com/$request_uri;
}

# Main config
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  # SSL config
  include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  # Error logs
  access_log /srv/logs/nginx.access.example.com.log;
  error_log srv/logs/nginx.error.example.com.log;

  # Root dir
  location / {
    root /srv/example.com/_site/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # Caching
  location ~ .php$ {
    root /srv/example.com/_site/;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    root /srv/example.com/_site/;
    expires 365d;
  }
  location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
    root /srv/example.com/_site/;
    expires 30d;
  }

  # SSL
  location /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I understand variables are not supported in NGINX config, so I have to manually define the log locations for example. Would there be a way to set a default location for all vhosts?

Yes, just define it in the `http` context of your config or stick with the default of your distro (e.g. `/var/log/nginx/access.log`).

> I use the same ssl-params.conf file for all vhosts. Can this be defaulted and disabled on a per-vhost basis?

It works the other way around you enable it where you need it through the `include` directive.

---

Here is a shorter config (untested):

```
http {
    error_log   /srv/logs/nginx.error.example.com.log;
    access_log  /srv/logs/nginx.access.example.com.log;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name .example.com;

        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        root /srv/example.com/_site/;

        include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                try_files $uri =404;
            }

            location ~* \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires 365d;
            }

            location ~* \.(pdf)$ {
                expires 30d;
            }

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }
    }
}
```